# dotnet not found in alpine docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine

USER root

RUN apk update
RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib wget
RUN apk add libgdiplus --repository https://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/

USER jenkins

RUN wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O $HOME/dotnet-install.sh
RUN chmod +x $HOME/dotnet-install.sh
RUN $HOME/dotnet-install.sh -c 5.0

RUN dotnet --info

EXPOSE 2376 23676
```

But when I run docker-compose, it gives me:

```
Building jenkins
failed to get console mode for stdout: Invalid identifier.
[+] Building 64.6s (10/11)
[+] Building 64.7s (11/11) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from jenkins.dockerfile               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 486B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine      1.6s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine@sha256:b2f3dd63864733  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN apk update                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libss  0.0s
 => [4/8] RUN apk add libgdiplus --repository https://dl-3.alpinelinux.or  7.8s
 => [5/8] RUN wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O $HOME/dotnet-i  2.2s
 => [6/8] RUN chmod +x $HOME/dotnet-install.sh                             0.3s
 => [7/8] RUN $HOME/dotnet-install.sh -c 5.0                              52.2s
 => ERROR [8/8] RUN dotnet --info                                          0.5s
------
 > [8/8] RUN dotnet --info:
#11 0.447 /bin/sh: dotnet: not found
------
ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build
```

I followed every step in Microsoft documentation but I keep failing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you find the console output from the "[7/8] RUN $HOME/dotnet-install.sh -c 5.0" step? Are there any errors or clues there? I'd also try looking at the image at that point to see if there's a dotnet binary/script somewhere else not in the path e.g. /usr/local/bin.

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I've never seen Docker suppress the output and just show you "step 7 took 52 seconds" like that. Best guess is that dotnet is installed somewhere under the Jenkins user's home directory, since you installed it as Jenkins not root, and it's just not in the user path. (Or maybe it added itself to the profile scripts but that wouldn't be available until you logged out and back in again - but I've never seen anything do that on Linux, even for an as-root install.) That may be enough for the Jenkins agent to use so maybe there's nothing to worry about here.

Comment: @Rup I think I found something. When I use volumes in the yml file, seems like the dotnet sdk instalation is getting lost. When I don't use volumes, dotnet sdk seems just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `jenkins/jnlp-slave:alpine` image

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave:alpine

USER root

RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib wget
RUN apk add libgdiplus --repository https://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet 

RUN wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
RUN chmod +x dotnet-install.sh
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c 3.1 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c 5.0 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c 6.0 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
```

Comment: When I execute .`/dotnet-install.sh -c 6.0 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet` I get the following error: `env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory` (I am running this on M1 Mac)

Answer (score 2):

To install .Net Core 5.0 SDK in a jenkins container with volumes configure I had to do the following:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine AS builder

    # Switch to root user to install .NET SDK
    USER root

    # Pre-requisits
    RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib wget
    RUN apk update

FROM builder

    # Download do script
    RUN wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O $HOME/dotnet-install.sh

    RUN chmod +x $HOME/dotnet-install.sh
    RUN $HOME/dotnet-install.sh -c 5.0


EXPOSE 2376 2376
```